# Code First Foreign Key - Multiplicity is not valid in Role

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

**My Model as below:**

```
public class Form1
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department", Prompt = "Please enter your department")]
    public string Department { get; set; }


    public  Form1 Form1{ get; set; }
    public  Form2 Form2 { get; set; }
}
```

Second Class (Need one to one relationship) so setting Foreign key

```
public class Form2
{
    [Key]
    public long Form2_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Form1")]
    public long Id { get; set; }


    //Mobile Home Page
    public string Location1 { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)] 

    //[ForeignKey("Id")]  //Even this is not working
    public  Form1 Form1 { get; set; }

}
```

Third class here. Same as above and needed One to One relationship Foreign Key.

```
public class Form3
{
    [Key]
    public long Form3_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Form1")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Rhombus")]
    public bool Rhombus { get; set; }


    public  Form1 Form1 { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting following error.

*One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Form2_Form1_Source' in relationship 'Form2_Form1'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.*

What wrong I am doing here?

Looks like I am struck up in this.!! Maybe Database first approach is better.

Answer (score 3):

For one-to-one relationships, EF expects that the tables are using the same primary key. And really, if it's a true one-to-one they probably should. So in your example, if you make ID the primary key on the Form2 and Form3 table, your one-to-one will work.

```
 public class Form1
 {
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department", Prompt = "Please enter your department")]
    public string Department { get; set; }       

   public  Form1 Form1{ get; set; }
   public  Form2 Form2 { get; set; }

}

   public class Form2
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }


    //Mobile Home Page
    public string Location1 { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)] 

    public  Form1 Form1Obj { get; set; }

}

public class Form3
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Rhombus")]
    public bool Rhombus { get; set; }


    public  Form2 Form2Obj { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It does not work: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'RecipeForm.Models.Form2' and 'RecipeForm.Models.Form1'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.